# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ... only for some packages

Tags: python, module, package, python-import

I am using Portable Msys2 under Win 10.
I have installed python 3.7 and 2.7.

I find errors when importing **only some packages**.
I guess I need to find the right setting of `PYTHONPATH`, but so far I could not.

All this was sparked by the error I got when importing `numpy` (indicated below).
Then I found other "similar" but not equal errors, and I am not sure if they have the same source.

As a reference,

```
$ env | grep -i python
PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/user1/.pythonrc
PYTHONPATH=( I will list options I tried below )
```

and my `.pythonrc` is listed at the bottom.

The directory pairs relevant for imports seem to be:

1. Pair `usr` and `usr_sp`:
   `C:\Users\user1\Documents\appls_mydocs\PortableApps\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\usr\lib\python3.7\`

   `C:\Users\user1\Documents\appls_mydocs\PortableApps\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\usr\lib\python3.7\site-packages`
2. Pair `mingw64` and `mingw64_sp`: `C:\Users\user1\Documents\appls_mydocs\PortableApps\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\mingw64\lib\python3.7\`

   `C:\Users\user1\Documents\appls_mydocs\PortableApps\MSYS2Portable\App\msys32\mingw64\lib\python3.7\site-packages`

For each option of `PYTHONPATH`, I tried importing (perhaps blindly) modules and packages that are present only in one or another directory pair.

1. In pair `mingw64`, not in pair `usr`:

   `msilib` is the only package present in `mingw64` that is not in `usr`.
   There are no modules present in `mingw64` that are not in `usr`.

   `cairo`, `colorama` and `numpy` are among many packages present in `mingw64_sp` that are not in `usr_sp`.
   `pytest` is one module present in `mingw64_sp` that is not in `usr_sp`.
2. In pair `usr`, not in pair `mingw64`:

   There are no packages present in `usr` that are not in `mingw64`.
   There are no modules present in `usr` that are not in `mingw64`.

   `pip` is the only package present in `usr_sp` that is not in `mingw64_sp`.
   `magic` is the only module present in `usr_sp` that are not in `mingw64_sp`.

The options I tried are:

1. Nothing in `PYTHONPATH`.
   Results below (**tl;dr**) suggest that `usr` and `usr_sp` are found, and `mingw64` and `mingw64_sp` are not.

   ---

   **tl;dr**:

   ```
   [~]$ unset PYTHONPATH
   [~]$ python3
   Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 26 2018, 08:23:20)
   [GCC 7.4.0] on msys
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   Reading /home/user1/.pythonrc
   readline is in /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-37m.dll
   >>> import sys
   >>> sys.path
   ['', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
   >>> import datetime
   >>> import json
   >>> import msilib
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msilib'
   >>> import cairo
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cairo'
   >>> import colorama
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'colorama'
   >>> import pip
   >>> import pytest
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytest'
   >>> import magic
   >>> exit()
   ```

   ---
2. `PYTHONPATH` with added `mingw64` pair.
   Results below (**tl;dr**) suggest that both pairs (`usr`, `usr_sp`), and (`mingw64`, `mingw64_sp`) are found.
   But there is something still missing **only for some packages** (in this case, `msilib`, `cairo`, `numpy`), while for others the configuration is sufficient (in this case, `colorama`).
   In addition, now something from `mingw64` shadows `usr` (see `import magic`).

   ---

   **tld;dr**:

   ```
   [~]$ env | grep -i python
   PYTHONSTARTUP=/home/user1/.pythonrc
   PYTHONPATH=/c/Users/user1/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7:/c/Users/user1/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages
   [~]$ python3
   Python 3.7.2 (default, Dec 26 2018, 08:23:20)
   [GCC 7.4.0] on msys
   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   Reading /home/user1/.pythonrc
   readline is in /usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-37m.dll
   >>> import sys
   >>> sys.path
   ['', '/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7', '/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
   >>> import datetime
   >>> import json
   >>> import msilib
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/msilib/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
       from _msi import *
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_msi'
   >>> import cairo
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairo/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
       from ._cairo import *  # noqa: F401,F403
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cairo._cairo'
   >>> import colorama
   >>> import numpy                        <----------------------- This sparked the question
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
       from . import multiarray
     File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
       from . import overrides
     File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 6, in <module>
       from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

   During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
       from . import core
     File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 71, in <module>
       raise ImportError(msg)
   ImportError:

   IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

   Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
   likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
   Here is how to proceed:
   - If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
     (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.
   - If you are simply trying to use the numpy version that you have installed:
     your installation is broken - please reinstall numpy.
   - If you have already reinstalled and that did not fix the problem, then:
     1. Check that you are using the Python you expect (you're using /usr/bin/python3),
        and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
        interfere with the Python and numpy versions you're trying to use.
     2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
        https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
        - how you installed Python
        - how you installed numpy
        - your operating system
        - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
        - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log
        Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
        an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

   Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
   >>> import pip
   >>> import pytest
   >>> import magic
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/magic.py", line 61, in <module>
       _open = _libraries['magic'].magic_open
     File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 369, in __getattr__
       func = self.__getitem__(name)
     File "/c/Users/ry16205/Documents/appls_mydocs/PortableApps/MSYS2Portable/App/msys32/mingw64/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __getitem__                 
       func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))                                                                                                                         
   AttributeError: function 'magic_open' not found
   ```

   ---

My `.pythonrc`:

```
import os
print( "Reading " + os.path.realpath(__file__) )

# enable syntax completion
try:
    import readline
    print( "readline is in " + readline.__file__ )
except ImportError:
    print("Module readline not available.")
else:
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

# From https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/interactive.html

# Add auto-completion and a stored history file of commands to your Python
# interactive interpreter. Requires Python 2.0+, readline. Autocomplete is
# bound to the Esc key by default (you can change it - see readline docs).
#
# Store the file in ~/.pystartup, and set an environment variable to point
# to it:  "export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pystartup" in bash.

import atexit
import os
#import readline
#import rlcompleter

historyPath = os.path.expanduser("~/.pyhistory")

def save_history(historyPath=historyPath):
    import readline
    readline.write_history_file(historyPath)

if os.path.exists(historyPath):
    #import readline
    readline.read_history_file(historyPath)

atexit.register(save_history)
del os, atexit, readline, rlcompleter, save_history, historyPath
```